# Static Generic Method in Class - Java

Tags: java, android, generics, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxJava on Android for doing some stuff,

I always do the same stuff on the observable before using it like this :

```
Observable<AnyObject> observable = getSomeObservable();
// The next 2 lines are the lines that i always add them to any Observable
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
```

Hence the Observable is generic and can be any object, if i want to add those two lines on it and return it in a Statis method, i need to make the method also Generic

What i was trying to do is to pass the observable by parameter, add set it up and return it back as following:

```
public class UtilsObservable<T> {

    public static Observable<T> setupObservable(Observable<T> observable) {
        return observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
}
```

I got a compile error here says:

```
UtilsObservable.this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

[image: pic]

***My Question is :***

So can this be done in anyway ? Generic method takes generic object modify it and return the same type ?

Comment: Where do you define the bounds for T?

Comment: @blahfunk it is Generic symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the generic type `T` is linked to a specific instance of the `UtilsObservable` class, but in a static context you don't have an instance to reference. You need to make the method generic, independent of the class's generic type.

```
public class UtilsObservable<T> {

    public static <T> Observable<T> setupObservable(Observable<T> observable) {
        return observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
}
```

Notice the additional `<T>` before the method type. That gives the method itself a generic type, which is no longer connected to an instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

First of all [don't break the chain](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/), please.

And second of all follow **resueman** answer:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> setupObservable(Observable<T> observable) {
    return observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, It was nice but i think it is exaggerating as in the article it says `ugly, confusing,no longer a series of operators and hard to follow ` !! according to what it is ugly and confusing? on android we almost always apply the very same schedules, why not to save some lines and time !?

Comment: @MBH There is some principles in OOP that should be followed. There are articles and books about that. As in OOP in rx there are another principles, that should be followed. It's not a requirement but a sign of good manners.